# Form Validation Help

Tags: ajax, validation, forms

Hi I'm trying to create a simple registration form with ajax validation. I've got the form working almost how I'd like... a message appears on the page with the errors for each field entered incorrectly.

The problem is all the error messages appear in one div together and I would like to have each field have its own div containing only its own error.

I think I need to wrap my error messages in xml and use something like this -

```
document.getElementById("feedback1").innerHTML= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

- but can't seem to get it working

Does anyone know how I should modify my code to do this?

Here is my source containing the 3 file I'm currently using - http://www.cultivatedesigns.ca/Uploads/ajax-validation.zip

And Here is my code for my ajax page only.

```
 var xmlHttp;

function regForm(thisform) {
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp==null) {
 alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
 return;
 }
 var formdata = "";
 formdata = "lname=" + thisform.elements['lname'].value + "&fname=" + thisform.elements['fname'].value + "&email=" + thisform.elements['email'].value + "&username=" + thisform.elements['username'].value + "&pass=" + thisform.elements['pass'].value + "&pass2=" + thisform.elements['pass2'].value;
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=formSubmitted;
    xmlHttp.open("POST", "adduser.php",true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", formdata.length);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlHttp.send(formdata);
    return false;
}

function formSubmitted() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete") { 
    xmlDoc=xmlHttp.responseXML;
document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
//document.getElementById("feedback1").innerHTML= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject() {
xmlHttp=null;
try
 {
 xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
catch (e)
 {
 try
  {
  xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
 catch (e)
  {
  xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 }
return xmlHttp;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can I recommend that you use jQuery or some other JS framework? It'll make your life a LOT easier.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your Javascript? Try running it through Firebug and tell us what errors you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out my problem it was just that my errors weren't being wrapped in an xml parent tag.

I so I had something like this

```
echo "<fname> </fname>";    
echo "<lname> </lname>";
```

And It should have been like this.

```
echo "<errors>";        
echo "<fname> </fname>";    
echo "<lname> </lname>";
ehco "</errors>"
```